# React Router App gets 404 on reload of subpage - serverless, no webpack

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I know this sounds exactly like a couple of older posts, but I've been through them, and they didn't help. I have a very simple React App: http://bentleytech.com. It navigates fine, until you try to reload a page, or if you try to access a page directly, such as: http://bentleytech.com/Contact. Then, you get a 404 error. Works fine when I run the code on localhost, but not the deployed version.

I am not using Express, so any solutions like a default app.use statement don't apply. I am not using a webpack, so telling me to change that config doesn't help either.

I have tried switching from BrowserRouter to HashRouter, and that caused my page to not load at all.

Any suggestions are welcome!

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import About from "./pages/About";
import Portfolio from "./pages/Portfolio";
import Contact from "./pages/Contact";

import Nav from "./components/Nav";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <>
        <Nav />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/About"><About /></Route>
          <Route exact path="/Portfolio"><Portfolio /></Route>
          <Route exact path="/Contact"><Contact /></Route>
          <Route path="/*"><About /></Route>
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Package.json:

```
  "name": "react-portfolio",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "Portfolio for Andrea C. Bentley",
  "homepage": "http://bentleytech.com",
```

Comment: I tried based on your code. I didn't find issue. Not sure its router issue. You can check demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-h97kbg

Comment: Interesting... yes, yours seems to work just fine. Not sure what the problem is then?

Comment: Share more data. Its hard to tell from this :-(

Comment: What should I share? I have no idea!

Comment: Try replicating your same code on stackblitz[https://stackblitz.com/] react sandbox. In that way anyone can see your code and fixed it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-router URLs don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

Comment: Thank you, but no. My app is a simple, client-side-only, server-less site. I am not using Node, Express, AWS, PHP, Apache, Nginx, IIS, Firebase, ASP.net, nor do I have a Webpack. The only solution that has worked for me is using HashRouter, which uses those awful hashtags in the URL. I would still love a solution that does not use HashRouter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to set base href in your index.html head section and it should work fine:

```
<base href="/" />
```

Comment: Oh! I haven't seen that suggestion before! I'll try that... thanks!

Comment: That did not seem to help, but thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it turns out that switching from **BrowserRouter** to **HashRouter** did solve the problem after all. I think I was having a separate issue with my test environment that caused it not to work before. Now, I have those hashtags in my url that I don't like, but I can live with that for a functioning app. Hope this helps someone else.